# Override BonCode Tomcat7 connector setting for a single site in IIS8

Tags: iis-8, tomcat7, settings

I have a Tomcat 7 instance behind IIS 8, connected with the BonCode connector installed for all sites — hence the `BonCodeAJP13.settings` file is under `C:\Windows`.

I need to override some settings (i.e. the `TomcatConnectErrorURL` parameter), for a specific site.

How do I do it? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to keep the global install you need to use a dynamic error page, e.g. a script that processes your connection error.
For example, Rather than going to 500.htm you would use 500.aspx. In your aspx page you need to detect the site context that is causing the error, then, present the right error for the site of your choosing.

-Brian