# Make IIS redirect to static html page when Tomcat offline

Tags: iis-8, tomcat7

I have a Tomcat 7 instance behind IIS 8; how do I make IIS return a static (site-specific) html page when Tomcat is offline / not available, etc?

The only way I found is with a BonCode setting, but (as you can see [in this question](https://serverfault.com/q/629515/242122)) I'm having troubles with its settings.

Comment: You should update your original question. Both are parts of the same problem.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGillier Not completely, I think; It would be if the only way to solve the problem stated here is by using the setting I mention in that other question.